# Ubuntu terminal close detect using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu

Where do I place signal handler function:

```
signal.signal(signal.SIGHUP, signal_handler)
```

Inside Python code to detect closure in main function and another functionality:

```
def signal_handler(sig, frame):
        logging.basicConfig(filename="newfile.log", format='%(asctime)s %(message)s',filemode='w')
        print("Inside handler")
```

To execute if user closes the Ubuntu terminal before main function executes?
Without signal.pause() for a program without loops

Example:

```
import signal
import sys
import logging
 
def main():
    print("Main function execution")
    signal.signal(signal.SIGHUP, signal_handler)
       
def signal_handler(sig, frame):
    logging.basicConfig(filename="newfile.log", format='%(asctime)s %(message)s',filemode='w')
    print("Inside handler")
    # Create and configure logger
    
if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Assume main function executes for 10-20 sec and closure is to be detected within that execution frame

Comment: Please show us what you tried. A signal handler should be exactly the right approach.

Comment: You'll want to [edit] your question, or risk having it closed as lacking the details you hide down here in comments. As you can see, posting code in comments doesn't really work anyway. See also the [help] and in particular [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask) as well as the guidance for providing a [mre].

Comment: I don't have Ubuntu with a GUI available easily, but my guess is that you simply did not see the output because you had closed the window where it would have been printed. Try actually writing to the log file.

Comment: (@AdarshUdupi Please read [Markdown Editing Help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).)

Comment: Here i have provided and example and described the issue, in my recent edit. Hope it filters everthing required. Assuming here that my main function takes some time say 10 s to complete and i have to detect closure by user, what approach should i use then? signal.pause() will halt my applciation which i donot want

Comment: this has nothing to do with OpenCV. I've removed the OpenCV tag. do not tag unrelated technologies.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `def main()` runs for 10 sec . Adding `signal.signal(signal.SIGHUP, HANDLER)` in main function `(if name==_main)` helped me detect terminal closure